# The type or namespace name 'VimApi' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, vmware, vsphere

I am getting the error -

> type or namespace name 'VimApi' could not be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)

I followed the below steps to generate the VimService2013 and VimService2013.XmlSerializersdll.

```
cd ..
if not exist VimService2013.dll (
    wsdl /n:VimApi /o:VimService.cs ..\..\wsdl\vim\vim.wsdl ..\..\wsdl\vim\vimService.wsdl
    csc /t:library /out:VimService2013.dll VimService.cs
    sgen /p VimService2013.dll
)

if not exist Vim25Service2013.dll (
    wsdl /n:Vim25Api /o:Vim25Service.cs ..\..\wsdl\vim25\vim.wsdl ..\..\wsdl\vim25\vimService.wsdl
    csc /t:library /out:Vim25Service2013.dll Vim25Service.cs
    sgen /p Vim25Service2013.dll
)
```

But still i am getting the error.

Comment: I am assuming you have a VS Project / solution. In your VS Project references folder do you have a reference to that dll?

Comment: Yes i have added the reference to the dll.